# Creating atlas of different layers on the same place (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, layers, atlas

I know the atlas function in QGIS can automate creation of maps of the same layer (say vegetation type) of different places (say natural reserves).

Is there a possibility to automate the creation of different maps with different layers (vegetation type, climate, hours of sun) of the same region or place?

So, kind of reversing the atlas function to have it cover the same area with different attributes.

Any suggestions or links to the answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can still use atlas generation to limit the print composer to one page. Similar to what @PieterB outlined,

1. Create a visibility preset for every map output you want and give it unique names.
2. Create the atlas coverage layer, and duplicate the feature as many times as the maps you need.
3. Add an attribute "Visibility" to the atlas layer, and put in the unique names of the presets as values.
4. Use data defined override to control the map theme using the "Visibility" field of your atlas layer.
   [image]

This method limits your print composer to one page which helps in keeping a consistent layout.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a preset for every theme you want to visualize.

- check and style the layers for the desired theme
- add a preset

[image]

- give it a name

Do this for each theme you want to create a map.

Go to printcomposer

- in the tab composition: add as many pages as themes you want to print out
- on each page add a map
- add the desired visibility preset for that map

[image]

If you want create an atlas you have to define the coverage layer for each page.