# Creating maps that look the same but display different data

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts

I want to make several maps of the same area displaying different data (e.g. population, GDP, currency...) on QGIS. I want everything to be the same way in the maps (area displayed, scale, position of the scale bar, inset map) except for the data that is shown.

So far I know how to create print layouts that display what I want, but if I make one for each type of data they will end up looking slightly different. How can I do it in a systematic way to achieve the same look in all of them?

Comment: like this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286098/creating-atlas-of-different-layers-on-the-same-place-qgis

Comment: Why will they "end up looking slightly different"? Not sure I understand the issue. But maybe view presents might help: https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/03/18/qgis-legend-tree-presets/ This way you can use one print composer, just change what is displayed on the map.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use map themes. You can turn on a set of layers while others are off and save it as a theme. Do this for as many layouts as you want to produce. Then in the layout, you can choose the theme which will show the layers that are turned on.

To create a theme, turn on the needed layers and click the second button (I believe) from the left in the layer panel (The one with a plus next to style painter. Using my phone so can't post screenshots).

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution using atlas that will not change any map extent, but will just go through different map themes. To do this, there is one difficulty to consider : the legend. As atlas are generated automatically, some manual adjustment on legend will not be possible. If you have always the same number of element / column in your legend, it might work very well. If not, then it could be sometimes difficult to get the result you want.

Here is the process, I will advise to try it with two or three themes first to have a try and then add new styles and themes.

## Define styles

For each thematic map you want to create, you have to create a style. Open the layer styling panel (F7), go to style manager (5th tab) create a style and then configure it as you wish. To have a nice legend, your style must define a legend label as clear as possible.
If one layer is used for different thematic map (GDP and GDP per capita) then you have to create as many style as you have thematic map.

## Create themes

On your layer tree, activate all the layer you want to set your first thematic map. For every layer you have activated, choose between the style you have created before(right click on it will give you an easy access).
When you think the map is set well, then  you can add themes named with a number and the name of the thematic you want to work (to sort it easily) :

[image]

Create one theme for every thematic map you want to create.

## Set your atlas to change map themes

You have to create a layer with no geometry that will have a column `theme_name` and a column `map_title`. This layer will be your atlas coverage layer. Create one feature for every theme you have and verify the name is the same as your themes names.

In the layout manager, you have to activate atlas and choose atlas coverage layer. Then select your map and in item properties check `follow map themes` and then choose data driven definition and set it to be : `attribute(@atlas_feature, 'theme_name')`.

You can activate atlas and then go through each of your atlas page to check it work well. If it work you can export the atlas.

Answer (score -1):

Read the [docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/overview_composer.html?#menus-and-tools).

> You can save the layout as a template and load it again in another session. Finally, generating several maps based on a template can be done through the atlas generator.

[image]