# Export Atlas - Different data - Same canvas

Tags: qgis, expression, atlas

On a defined study area (map below), I have thousands of geotagged information.

[image: Data distribution]

I would like to export an Atlas of these data, each export displaying one information.
(Ex: For the same area of study, I want to export the location of each same information (like species) ; one map with "Pterocarpus indicus", another with "Swietenia mahagoni", etc.), see maps below).

[image: Pterocarpus]
[image: Swietenia]

For now, I do it this way:

I use two layers:

- The point layer ("SPECIES_LIST") which contain all the information (in the field "Correspond").
  [image: Layer1]
- A second layer ("Liste_taxons") which has no geometry and list one occurrence of each information contained in field "Correspond" of the first layer.
  [image: Layer2]

[image: Layers]

> In the layout => Atlas, I use the second layer as "coverage layer", with "field1" as page name, which contain the list of each occurrence of the layer "SPECIES_LIST").
> [image: Atlas_layout]

> The symbology of the first layer is a rule-based symbology, following this expression:
> "field" = 'xxx' AND "field" = @atlas_pagename
> [image: Legend]

The Atlas follow the list in the second layer (so I have one export for each unique information).
The symbology is related to the name of the current atlas page, it is automatically filtrated (data is displayed when @atlas_pagename and "correspond" have the same content).

I have a lot of information to show, and, as you can see, writing a rule-based symbology for each information can be very long. I don't know a faster way to define a rule-based symbology.

---

Furthermore, I found another way to do it with themes. As explained on this discussion:
[Creating maps that look the same but display different data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404173/creating-maps-that-look-the-same-but-display-different-data)

This solution is also very long and any change can force the user to start from the beginning.

---

Do you know a faster way to export an Atlas, displaying only one information at a time? As shown in my example.

For example: Instead of using two layers (SPECIES_LIST and Liste_taxons), in the Atlas, is it possible to use a filter to get a list (from the layer SPECIES_LIST), with one occurrence of each information (from 2038 line we have 45 occurrences)?

> An expression which select only one occurrence of each different information in my first layer, so the Atlas can export the right number of pages (and not 2038).

[image: Atlas]

Comment: Not so clear. Can you show example of your data?

Comment: Yeah, we definitely need images on this one. Especially of your atlas settings, and of your desired outcome.

Comment: As requested, I edited my post.

Comment: I'm presenting the method I follow, and try to have information on how I could do it faster, because right now, it is quite long (exporting a list of unique occurrences (I do it on Excel), + manually writing a rule-based symbology).